# Horizontal scroll with hover and drag support

Tags: jquery

I got 25 images inside a div in a horizontal way, when the site loads it just show 12 or 16 max so I need a solution who let me scroll horizontally using the mouse (hover). If I move my mouse to the right, I could see the rest of the images and example here:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z27yf.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is this plugin : http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

Am I right ? ;)

Comment: Jibou Sr Yes! And thanks for your awesome and quick reply but i need a drag feature too, thats the main problem :/ Im using this as example [link](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/basicDemo.htm) but the full idea is here: http://wearehunted.com/ so my idea is get to rows sliding and the example just let me have one so if you could help me ill be great! Thanks again!

Comment: You could try to mix the smoothdivscroll plugin with this one : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dragscroller . I'm not suree that will be simple though ;)

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of SmoothDivScroll has suppor t for drag and swipe scrolling.